# Vicious circle with $\int_1^2{\ln x \over x}{dx}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

> Calculate $$E(Ω)=\int_1^2{\ln x \over x}{dx}$$
> $E$ derives from the greek word "εμβαδόν" which in English means area. $Ω$ is the specific "area" that is being calculated by the integral.

**Personal work:**

$$E(Ω)=\int_1^2{\ln x \over x}{dx}= \int_1^2{\ln x {1\over x}}{dx}=\int_1^2{\ln x (|\ln x|)'}{dx}=[\ln x|\ln x|]_1^2-\int_1^2(\ln x)'|\ln x|dx=\cdots=\ln4-\int_1^2 {1\over x}|\ln x|\,dx$$

I've been taught in school that when I have an integral form like this: $P(x)*\ln(kx)$ I always rewrite the $P(x)$ as a derivative. My problem is that it is a vicious circle and I always get $$\int_1^2{\ln x}{(|\ln x|)'}.$$ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see a function and its derivative in the integrand...

Comment: Note that $(ln2)^2 \not = ln4$

Comment: $$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{\log x}{x}\,dx\stackrel{x\mapsto e^t}{=}\int_{0}^{\log 2} t\,dt = \frac{\log^2(2)}{2}.$$ Why to call $E(\Omega)$ something which does not depend on $\Omega$ (whatever it is)?

Comment: Obtaining from integration by parts a result of the form $I=J+aI$ with $a\ne 1$, as you have done, is common; it obtains $I=J/(1-a)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $u=\ln x$ hence $du=\frac {dx}{x}$

The integral changes to $$\int_0^{\ln2} udu=\frac {u^2}{2}=\frac {(\ln 2)^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

You have just concluded that if $$I = \int_{x=1}^2 \frac{\log x}{x} \, dx,$$ then $$I = (\log 2)^2 - I.$$  Consequently, $$2I = (\log 2)^2$$ and $$I = \frac{(\log 2)^2}{2}.$$

Note that your original result is not correct; $(\log 2)^2 \ne \log 4$.

As others have commented, an approach via direct substitution and not integration by parts is simpler and achieves the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute $$t=\ln x$$ then you will get $$\mathrm dt=\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm dx$$